# Limit of the set sequence

Tags: general-topology

I studied the proof of the statement:
If $A_n↗$ then $\lim _{n→∞}A_n = \bigcup_{n∈ \mathbb N} A_n:$

We need to show that if $A_n$ is monotonic non-decreasing, then $\limsup A_n = \liminf A_n =\bigcup_{n} A_n$. Since $A_i⊂A_{i+1}$, we have $\bigcap_{k≥n} A_k = A_n$,

and
$\liminf A_n = ⋃_{n∈ \mathbb N}⋂_{k≥n} A_k= ⋃_{n∈ \mathbb N} A_n,$
$\limsup A_n=⋃_{n∈ \mathbb N}⋂_{k≥n}A_k⊂⋃_{k∈ \mathbb N}A_k=\liminf A_n⊂\limsup A_n.$

Can someone explain me the place $⋃_{n∈ \mathbb N}⋂_{k≥n}A_k⊂⋃_{k∈ \mathbb N}A_k$ in the last row?

Comment: For any sequence $(A_n)_{n\in N}$ of sets, and for any $x,$ we have $x\in \lim \sup A_n$ iff $\{n\in N:x\in A_n\}$ is infinite, and we have $ x\in \lim \inf A_n$ iff $\{n\in N: x \not \in A_n\}$ is finite.....If $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$ for every $n,$ then each of these conditions is readily seen to be equivalent to $x\in \cup_{n\in N}A_n.$

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k$, then by definition there is some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ (from the union) such that for all $ k \ge n_0$ ( from the intersection) we have $x \in A_k$. In particular, we have that $x \in A_{n_0} \subseteq \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k$.

Without points:

for all $n$ we have $\bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k \subseteq A_n$.

So the unions over $n$ have the same relation.